# Compiling geniePi.h 4D Systems

Tags: c, gcc, raspberry-pi

I am trying to compile this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <geniePi.h>

int counter = 0;

int main()
{

if (genieSetup ("/dev/ttyAMA0", 115200) < 0)
{
    printf("Failed to connect");
}

for (;;)
{
    counter++;
    genieWriteObj (GENIE_OBJ_COOL_GAUGE,    0, counter) ;
    sleep(10);
}



return 0;
}
```

I have been running the command

```
sudo gcc genietest.c
```

I keep getting the error

```
 genietest.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `genieSetup'
 genietest.c:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `genieWriteObj'
```

It seams to me that the geniePi.h is not getting included

I installed under the Pi directory using

```
 make
 sudo make install
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to add the genie library to your compile line. Something like "sudo gcc genietest.c -lgenie" depending on where the genie library is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using [this](https://github.com/4dsystems/ViSi-Genie-RaspPi-Library/blob/master/Makefile) library ?

Generally, when wanting to use a library, you need to link to that library. In this case:

```
gcc genietest.c -lgeniePi
```

The default makefile seems to install libgeniePi.so under /usr/local/lib , if that path is not in the default search path for your compiler, you need to tell it where to look:

```
gcc genietest.c -L/usr/local/lib -lgeniePi
```

Comment: This got it to compile but it did not do anything when I ran it. Any Ideas?

Comment: I've no idea what's even supposed to happen. The README.md file of the library states a whole bunch of stuff you have to do first, did you at least do those ? But it sure should dod something, either print "Failed to connect", or run forever (until you kill it)

Comment: I added an Else after the if that should print something if it succeeds but there is still no output. I have installed all of the parts stated in the README.

Comment: Then genieSetup ("/dev/ttyAMA0", 115200) probably hangs, which probably means for whatever reason it isn't able to properly communicate with the device you've hooked up to your raspberry pi.

Comment: Would the gcc be ignoring the stdio import?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. you need stdio.h for using printf(), there's nothing wrong with that part. You however have one error, your printf() call have no newline , \n, at the end, so you might not be able to see any output on the terminal.